# How to determine how many runs are needed for a Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, simulation

I have been reading a lot of references online, but people seem to have different sorts of equations to determine the required number of runs.

[image: Description that came with the formula]

This formula was the one I obtained from an article and I am wondering if this is indeed the right one. Also, how can I use this formula?

Edit:
I will use the Monte Carlo simulation to generate random numbers from a normal distribution. These random numbers will be used to represent demand as the random variates.

The model of interest is an inventory model where demand will be the variable to be simulated. The properties of the demand is that it is normally distributed, mean is non-stationary over time, independent and not correlated, and stochastic over a time horizon.

I performed a linear program using MATLAB, however, the solution of the problem is deterministic by nature--meaning it will always give the same "optimum" value for the specified parameter settings. What I want to achieve is to incorporate randomness into the system by using a Monte Carlo simulation which will test my model for robustness when different "real" demands are incorporated.

I would say a 95-98% accuracy would be good, but it is completely arbitrary because I do not really have anything to base it on.

Below is my code for the generation of the "real" demand values.
Where:
n= number of runs;
average(i)=mean of demand;
a(i)=standard deviation of demand;
CV=coefficient of variation;
sim_d="real" demand values;

[image: This is the code for my generation of random variates]

This is the flowchart of the process to further explain the procedure (click to see)

[image: Flowchart]

Comment: Rather than quote some random formula which may or may not relate to what you're trying to do, please describe what you're trying to simulate, what outcomes you want to look at and (if possible at this stage)  what kind of accuracy you need (/uncertainty you can tolerate) on them.

Comment: What article? Give a reference. Ans.: A sufficient number. How sufficient is determined depends on what is being tested, speaking of which, what IS being tested?

Comment: I don't understand: in a linear programming (optimization) problem, you have variables $(x_1,\dots,x_p)=\mathbf{x}$, linear constraint $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}$, and a linear objective function $f(x_1,\dots,x_p)=\sum_{i=1}^p c_ix_i=\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{x}$. What are you considering uncertain? The coefficient vector $\mathbf{c}$? The constraint matrix $\mathbf{A}$? The constraint vector $\mathbf{b}$? All of the above?

Comment: Thanks for including the process, but I still don't understand what "demand" is in the linear programming problem. It surely isn't one of the $x_i$, because those are not *inputs* to the optimization problem, in the sense that you don't assign a value to them in order to solve the problem.  You assign values to $\mathbf{c}, \ \mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, and then you find an optimal value $\mathbf{x}^*=(x_1^*,\dots,x_p^*)$ for your variables.

Comment: DeltaV, only one variable will be subject to randomness while keeping everything constant. That is the demand variable. For instance, demand=[30, 20] -> Input to and then run linear program -> Order 56 burgers -> Inject randomness into demand -> random demand using a mean of 30 and 20 and its corresponding standard deviation=[32 25] -> Incurs a stock-out in this example because "real demand" is total to 57 while the order quantity was only 56.

Comment: I think I (sort of) understood what you're doing. Now, what uncertainty do you want to estimate with Monte Carlo? The uncertainty in the number of burgers ordered? The probability of this "stock-out", i.e., how often the number or burgers orderered may be less than the number or burgers ordered? Ps not so important, but just for curiosity's sake, why do you have two values of demand? Do you have two restaurants in your problem? Or is it the demand forecast in two successive days?

Comment: DeltaV, Actually it is an input to the linear program. Although I kind of understand why you are confused. There is no way to actually incorporate that normally distributed demand into the linear program. However, the demand was used as follows: A heuristic developed to solve for the upper bounds of the order quantities was used where the mean of the demand was an input to this heuristic (note: normal distribution has no closed form)->The heuristic has an output of a table of deterministic order quantities -> a mixed integer program was used to pull out these orders on certain conditions

Comment: That's precisely what I'm saying: since it's one of the inputs, it's not one of the variables you're optimizing for. In other words, you *assign* (input) a demand, and you *compute* (solve the linear programming problem for) a number of burgers ordered.

Comment: The values I want estimate are a lot: stock-outs, perish of goods (expired), cost, service level (demand fulfilled/available stock). Assuming that the model told me to order 50 burgers. How well does this solution work when randomness in injected in demand when I simulated "real" demand values? That is the question. And for your curiosity, it is demand forecast of two days (or periods). Yes it is not a decision variable, but is an input to clear it up.

Comment: So, you re-run the model multiple times with random demands, and for each couple of random demands you get a number of burgers predicted by the model. Right? If this is the setting, I can answer your question.

Comment: Almost there, but not exactly. The decision variable is how many burgers. This is then held constant. We change only the demand values to represent realistic demands. Then the information of interest is the stock-outs, cost, and etc. What I was asking in the question was: how many times do i need to simulate the demand values. For instance, do i need 500 simulated demand runs to say that it is accurate? e.g. (demand=[32 18] - 1st run, demand=[28, 24] - 2nd run,..., until 500th run]

Comment: It's still not clear to me which is the output random variable whose mean you would like to estimate with the Monte Carlo method. Different outputs will require a different number of Monte Carlo runs, so let's concentrate on **one** output. Would the average number of stock-out events over 13 following days be an RV of interest for you?

Comment: Yes it would be of interest. Stock-outs and also the service level is a function of demand.

Comment: The normal distribution is a limiting distribution with finite moments. Per the many comments already made, a decision of "how many" simulations to run is a function of the behavior(s) you are trying to represent. Do you want to express the mass or density of the normal PDF or are you interested in the extremes? In financial optimization, the prescribed number of simulations is commonly put at 10,000 -- this works in terms of defining the density of the normal PDF. To capture extreme tail behaviors based on the normal, 150 million simulations may not be enough.

Comment: @DJohnson, of course there's not a magic number $N$ which, for all problems, will ensure that you get a certain accuracy at a given confidence level. The only thing you can say in general is that if $N$ runs give you a certain accuracy at a fixed confidence level, you need 4 times as much runs to halve the confidence interval width, since the standard error of the MC estimator is inversely proportional to the square root of the number of runs. However, for specific cases where the hypotheses behind MC estimation are valid, you do have procedures to estimate $N$ for that case, as I showed.

Comment: if one of the answers answered your question, you can [accept an answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) by clicking on the tick sign to the left of the question, below the number of votes, or if you think no answer is correct, you may leave a comment explaining what you would need to be discussed (as long as it's not another question: in that case you have to post a new question).

Answer (score 6):

The setting is a bit different from what I'm used to, but I think this is a classic Uncertainty Quantification (UQ) approach: specifically, it's Forward Uncertainty Propagation. The approach has limits, since you **assume** the demand distribution, instead than estimating it from data. Anyway, let's consider the following setting: with your model, you compute $C$, the number of burgers ordered over $p$ days. Using a constant coefficient of variation $\lambda$ and a vector of means $\boldsymbol{\mu}=(\mu_1,\dots, \mu_p)$, you define a random vector $\mathbf{d}=(d_1,\dots,d_p)$, whose components are independent, normally distributed with means given by $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and standard deviations $(\sigma_1=\lambda\mu_1,\dots, \sigma_p=\lambda\mu_p)$. Then, we generate a random sample $D=(\mathbf{d}_1,\dots,\mathbf{d}_N)$ of size $N$ from the distribution of this vector:

```
set.seed(25)
C <- 50
N <- 500
lambda <- 0.1
means <- c(30, 20)
p <- length(means)

demands <- rnorm(N * p, mean = means, sd = lambda * means ) # vector of length p*N
```

Now, for each vector $\mathbf{d}_i=(d_{i1},\dots,d_{ip})$, you either had a stock-out event or not, depending on whether $\sum_{j=1}^p d_{ij} > C$ or not. In other words, the occurence of a stock-out is a Bernoulli random variable with mean $p$ and standard deviation $(1-p)p$. Let's build the vector of stock-out events:

```
seqs <- seq_along(demands)
orders_over_p_days  <- tapply(demands, rep(seqs, each = p)[seqs], FUN = sum) # vector of length N
stock_outs <- orders_over_p_days > C # logical vector, 0 if we had enough burgers for p days otherwise 1
```

The Monte Carlo method estimates the probability $p$ of a stock-out event using the sample mean of this vector. In other words:

$$\hat{p}_N=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N p_i}{N}$$

$\hat{p}_N$ is the Monte Carlo estimator. Note that for each $i$, $p_i$ is either 0 (no stock-out) or 1 (stock-out). For example, in our case the value of the Monte carlo estimator is

```
phat <- sum(stock_outs)/N
> phat
#[1] 0.488
```

Since we have independent and identically distributed samples $p_i$, then, for $N\to\infty$, the distribution of this random variable

$$Z_N=\sqrt{N}\frac{\hat{p}_N-p}{\sqrt{(1-p)p}}$$

converges pointwise to a standard normal distribution. You can use this result to get approximate confidence intervals for your estimate of $p$, and from that, an estimate for the number of runs required to estimate $p$ to within a tolerance $\epsilon$, with a confidence level $\gamma$. Skipping the math, an approximate expression for $N$ would be

$$N=\frac{(1-p)p\left(\Phi^{-1}(\frac{1+\gamma}{2})\right)^2}{\epsilon^2}$$

where $\Phi^{-1}(x)$ is the quantile function of the standard normal distribution. Clearly, there is a problem here: the estimate for $N$ contains the unknown $p$. A practical solution is to run the Monte Carlo simulation for an initial number of runs, say, $N_{in}=500$, and compute $\hat{p}_{N_{in}}$. Using $\hat{p}_{N_{in}}$ we get an initial, crude estimate $(1-\hat{p}_{N_{in}})\hat{p}_{N_{in}}$ for $(1-p)p$, which leads to the approximate estimate for the total number of runs:

$$N=\frac{(1-\hat{p}_{N_{in}})\hat{p}_{N_{in}}\left(\Phi^{-1}(\frac{1+\gamma}{2})\right)^2}{\epsilon^2}$$

In deriving this formula we implicitly used quite a crude estimate for the confidence interval. For this reason, it's a good idea to increase the number of runs with respect to what you got from this formula, and to check the behavior of your estimator as the number of runs increases.

As an illustration, let's assume a confidence level $\gamma=0.95$ and an absolute accuracy $\epsilon = 0.01$, meaning that you would like to estimate the probability of a stock-out in $p$ days with an error of $\pm 0.01$, at a confidence level $0.95$. In our example we get:

```
gamma   <- 0.95
epsilon <- 0.01
q <- qnorm((1+gamma)/2)
N <- ceiling((1-phat)*phat*q^2/epsilon^2)
#[1] 9599
```

I would usually increase $N$ consistently, but let's use $N=10000$ just for the sake of example:

```
N <- 10000
demands <- rnorm(N * p, mean = means, sd = lambda * means )    
seqs <- seq_along(demands)
orders_over_p_days  <- tapply(demands, rep(seqs, each = p)[seqs], FUN = sum)     
stock_outs <- C < orders_over_p_days 

phat <- sum(stock_outs)/N
#[1] 0.4923
```

We can also plot the trend of our estimate against $N$:

```
sample_size <- seq_along(stock_outs)
phat <- cumsum(stock_outs)/sample_size
op <- par(mar = c(5, 5, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(sample_size, phat, type = "l", xlab = "N", ylab =expression(hat(p)))
```

[image]

We conclude that an (approximate) $95\%-$confidence interval for $p$ is $0.49\pm0.01$.

PS the above formula is valid if $\epsilon$ is an absolute error: if you're interested in the relative error, then the approximate formula becomes

$$N=\frac{\frac{(1-\hat{p}_{N_{in}})}{\hat{p}_{N_{in}}}\left(\Phi^{-1}(\frac{1+\gamma}{2})\right)^2}{\epsilon^2}$$

Comment: You might consider saving this to a separate, more clarified question, as an answer to that new question, the question here may wind up being closed (by NOT me, BTW, & +1 from me).

Comment: @Carl thanks for the +1 and for the info.I will save this abswerand, if a new question gets posted, I will post it again.

Comment: @DeltaIV Hello, I am sorry for leaving a comment in this old post, but where are your formulas for calculating the ideal number of trials from? Is there any paper that talks about the formula that you presented here?

Comment: Your formula for $Z_N$ is missing a factor of $\sqrt{N}.$

Comment: @whuber good catch, thanks - fixed. Let me know if you spot anything else. Just out of curiosity, how did you notice? Do you know the formula by heart, or is it because you can quickly recall the proof? You might also have computed the variance of $Z_N$ and saw that it wasn't 1, but I don't think that's how you noticed the mistake.

Comment: I'm afraid it's more mundane than that: earlier today somebody posted a new question asking whether that formula was correct or not!

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, the distribution generated by your deterministic function, based on the normally distributed inputs, may not itself be normal. Nor might it be solvable in closed form. However, in either or both cases, you can analyze the resulting distribution empirically, from the results of running the Monte Carlo distribution many times, and looking at the empirical variance, and other statistical measures of interest, of the resulting empirical samples.

Of course, if your distribution is analyzable in closed form, and is Gaussian, given Gaussian input, you might be able to derive a closed-form formulae for the variance of the output distribution, as a function of the variance and mean of the input Gaussian distribution.

Comment: +1 For effort, and, I do not like downvotes that come without constructive comments, pass it forward....

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to complicate this. Monitor the metric that you're calculating, then stop when it stops changing.

For instance, if you're calculating the probability of an event, then you monitor the quantity $$\hat p=\frac{n_i}{i},$$
where $n_i$ - number of observations of an event after $i$ simulations. Set a threshold such as 0.01 and then watch $\Delta p_i=p_i-p_{i-1}$ or $\delta p_i=\Delta p_i/p_i$, once $\Delta p_i<0.01$ or $\delta p_i<0.01$ stop the simulations. The former is the absolute error and the latter is relative error.

The final $i$ is the number you're looking for.

The only time this will not work if when you have to know $i$ in advance for some reason, e.g. for capacity planning purposes, and you absolutely cannot do any trial runs. In this case you have a problem. In the example above you could try approximations if you know the order of magnitude of $\hat p$. You could use Wald's formula for variance to back out $i$ like this:
$$\sigma=\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/i}$$
The problem's that if you're using variance reduction techniques (which you should) then these formulas don't work that well: they'll overestimate the number of simulations.